# Как удалить все элементы массива содержащие определенное значение

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется массив с id товаров из 1С у некоторых товаров несколько id и в них стоит значение 'many'. Вопрос как удалить все элементы массива содержащие 'many'?

Comment: в цикле пробежаться, проверяя на это значение

Comment: @DrAmx структуру массива не мешало бы опубликовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array (
      1 => 'many_ids1werwer4',
      2 => 'exmpl',
      3 => 'gooddata', 
      4 => 'good_not_many_good'
    )  ;     
     $bad_values = array('#', 'many');
            foreach ($arr as $key => $haystack) {
                foreach ($bad_values as $needle) {
                    if (strstr($haystack, $needle)) {
                        unset($arr[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Вот так, например, удалять будем по ключу (`$key`) вашего массива `$arr` из 1C элементы в которых найдется вхождение из массива `$bad_values` (специально сделал массивом, вдруг понадобится еще несколько вписать условий).